# Detect on blur outside of input text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, blur

I have two input box with different id. i need to call blur function only if i click outside of my input box.

Tried with below code

```
$('#voc1,#voc2').on('blur', function (e) {

    console.log("calling on blur1111");

});
```

But on clicking other input box blur function is being called. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: can you use console.log($(this))

Answer (score 0):

You can use `relatedTarget` on the event to check which element is causing the first one to lose focus. Note that `relatedTarget` can be null depending on what is happening, so you'll need to check that first. Then you can look at the `id` and see if it's one of your inputs.

```js
$('#voc1,#voc2').on('blur', function (e) {
  let id;
  if (e.relatedTarget) {
    id = e.relatedTarget.id;
  }
  if ((id == 'voc1') || (id == 'voc2')) {
    console.log(`Doing nothing because ${id} was clicked.`);
  } else {
    console.log('Something else was clicked so do something.');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='voc1' /><input type='text' id='voc2' />
```

Comment: @Sudha Instead of saying *Thank you* in comment, Please accept the answer and vote up.

Comment: @Pedram.. sorry folk. i have joined recently and have  less reputation.. so not able to vote.